Why MySQL JSON_EXTRACT Not work in WHERE condition?
I'll try this:
SELECT * FROM `gass_pedan` WHERE json_extract(`cars_info`, '$.driver_id') = 4;

which wrong in the above syntax?, also I'm using:
SELECT * FROM `gass_pedan` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`cars_info`, '4', '$.driver_id')

this is my JSON:
{"mxrid":2,"mxrno":"11","driver_id":"4","drname":"carl","cartype":"mixer"}


this is my server information: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
#3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "The document is empty." at position 0.


The error message seems clear. You have an empty cars_info, that's not valid JSON.

Set the value to NULL rather than an empty string if you have no information. Or you could use an empty object {}.

See the updated version please

I can't reproduce the error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8N5ntXgiTLQhsGZocdz9J2/0

You're right, I'm also shocked, because same syntax in my localhost are working very will, but in my web internet server not work !

Are you sure you don't have some rows with an empty cars_info?

yes I've some cars_info empty rows

Try WHERE cars_info != '' AND JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(cars_info, '$.driver_id')) = 4

YESSSSS, YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT, THANK YOU SO MUCH! put that comment in the ANSWER POST please

what does select @@sql_mode,version(); show on your localhost and internet server?

if you have empty cars_info values, you need to avoid calling JSON_EXTRACT() on those values. It will ignore NULL values, but empty strings cause an error.
SELECT * 
FROM `gass_pedan` 
WHERE `cars_info` != '' AND json_unquote(json_extract(`cars_info`, '$.driver_id')) = '4';

You also need to use json_unquote(). Otherwise it returns a string with literal " around it, which isn't equal to the number. You can use the ->> shorthand for JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))
SELECT * 
FROM `gass_pedan` 
WHERE `cars_info` != '' AND `cars_info`->>'$.driver_id' = '4';


note that = 4 will do a numeric comparison, finding many other values than just "4":  https://dbfiddle.uk/fCUwofMV   you likley want = "4"

@ysth If the value is always numeric, it's irrelevant.

it's just code smell, something that is sometimes wrong, so you should avoid doing it even when it doesn't make a difference so you more easily notice other times.  a similar thing would be (in perl) /foo$/ to check if a string ends in foo.  that's not what that regex does, it will also find strings that end with "foo\n".  you should just use the correct /foo\z/ so what your code does is what you mean, even when the string can't have a newline.
